# Fluid layout with fixed-width sidebar bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a fixed-sidebar-with-fluid-content layout working. I've run into a problem where the sidebar is at `height: 100%`, but it doesn't seem to be filling the whole window.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/ZqycY/2/. The green sidebar should go all the way down.

Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the issue with `height: 100%;` setting. When you resize the browser to shorten it, that sidebar will just cover the whole height of the browser window. You may try the following alternative CSS:

```
/*html, body { height: 100%}*/
body {    background-color: #1db34f;}

#side-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
/*    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1db34f;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;    */
    text-align: center;
}

#center-panel {
    margin-left: 280px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#center-panel .row-fluid {overflow: auto;}
#center-panel .large {height: 400px; padding: 10px; background-color: #f17f49;}
```

Comment: but this really doesn't change the height of the "side-panel" does it?
all that have been done is that the bg color of body is changed

Comment: agree. the height for #side-panel is no longer needed.

Comment: right. I had a border on the right of the side-panel, but now have one on the left of the center-panel. makes more sense to me, since the center panel content is what will be changing most.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for a fixed sidebar, it should be `#side-panel { position: fixed; }`. Hope [this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/v9HD9/)