# Prevent y-overflow when adding small left margin to bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Background:

I am trying to create a **collapsible** sidebar navigation menu based off of the bootstrap admin panel example... https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

**Problem:**

When the admin bar is in collapsed mode there is a small bar of icons showing. I add `margin-left: 50px` to the main content so that there is space for the left bar but then it pushes my main content off to the right of the screen.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

What I have so far:

**My markup**

```
<!-- top navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            Teach
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            Config
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- end top navigation -->

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- sidebar navigation -->
                <nav id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-faded sidebar">

                    <div class="sidebar-header">
                        <a id="toggleSidebar" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar-section">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Bookings</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Payments</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Classes</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar-section">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Courses</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Curriculum</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar-section">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Groups</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Students</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Teachers</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar-section">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span>Marketing</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                </nav>
                <!-- end sidebar navigation -->

                <!-- main content -->
                <main id="mainContent" class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </main>
                <!-- end main content -->

            </div>
        </div>
```

My css

```
/*bootstrap style*/
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
    border-right: 1px solid #444444;
    background: #353C3E;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/*sidebar button*/
#toggleSidebar {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#toggleSidebar i {
    color: white;
}

.sidebar-header {

}

.sidebar-header a {
    text-align: right;
}

.sidebar-section {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #444444;
    list-style: outside none none;
}

.sidebar-section .nav-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
}

.sidebar-section i {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-section a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #292b2c;
}

.sidebar-section a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #777777;
}

.sidebar .active {
    background: #999999;
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff;
}

.sidebar .active i {
    color: white;
}

/*when collapsed*/
.sidebar-smaller {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar-smaller div li a span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-smaller i {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.sidebar-smaller .sidebar-header a {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-smaller .active {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    border-left: none;
}

.content-wider {
    margin-left:54px;
}
```

My jQuery toggle code

```
$(function(){

            // cache the dom
            $sidebar       = $('#sidebar');
            $toggleSidebar = $('#toggleSidebar');
            $mainContent   = $('#mainContent');
            toggled        = false;

            $toggleSidebar.click(function(){

                if (toggled === false) {

                    // shrink the sidebar
                    $sidebar.addClass('sidebar-smaller');
                    $sidebar.removeClass('col-sm-3 col-md-2');

                    $mainContent.addClass('content-wider col-12');
                    $mainContent.removeClass('col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2');

                    toggled = true;

                } else {

                    // expand the sidebar
                    $sidebar.addClass('col-sm-3 col-md-2');
                    $sidebar.removeClass('sidebar-smaller');

                    $mainContent.addClass('col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2');
                    $mainContent.removeClass('content-wider col-12');

                    toggled = false;

                }


                // remove the class col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3

                // add the class col-sm-12 col-md-12 pt-3


            });

        });
```

Comment: Posting your code is great. However, it is much more helpful when you use it to create a [mcve] of your problem. You can make sure all required assets are loaded, that the problem is reproduce-able and you could also give indications on screen sizes at which the problem occurs. It helps a lot and speeds up the process, as well as greatly increasing your chances of getting quality, effective answers.

Comment: Hi Adrei, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kd1pr63v/

Comment: As I can see, side bar has position fixed, so it should overlap main-content when main-content has class col-*12? so you could set not `margin-left`, but `padding-left` to `.content-wider`?

Comment: @ Banzay, this indeed works! Thanks!

Comment: I put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the margin left to the content If you're using the correct col-**-** classes on the nav and main elements. They'll behave exactly like a grid.

I don't think you need the offsets either.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you mean add a col-1 to the nav and a col-11 to the main content? In this case I would prefer a fixed width sidebar of 50px so that it fits the icons that os why I am specifying a margin...

Comment: If that's the case you're better of just using floating and disregard using col classes. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16964252

Comment: @PedroCosta Your answer is correct, but it could use a more info as per: why is it a bad UX practice to use Bootstrap's `row>col` for sidebar nav and which are common alternatives. Are you going to expand your answer or do you prefer I add a more elaborate one?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm currently on mobile, I'll expand my answer as soon as possible. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Apologies for the ill thought out question, there is a ton of info on this online already. Appreciate the answers.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst not a problem, glad to have helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone... just in case someone is struggling with something similar this helped... http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4OZ8R

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, side bar has position fixed, so it should overlap `main-content` when `main-content` has class `col-*-12`? so you could set not `margin-left`, but `padding-left` to `.content-wider`?